# Is it possible to print an image with a print button directly, Without showing the printer Dialogue?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a program with visual basic (Visual Studio 2015). I want to click a button and print an image, but I don’t want to show the PrinterDialog (click [here](http://prntscr.com/8vawmg) to view the screenshot).

I would like to print it with just one click because this program is for public usage! How can I disable or skip this?

Comment: VS2015 is VB.Net not VBA, you should edit and retag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can print to the default printer like this:

```
Sub PrintFile(ByVal fileName As String)
    Dim myFile As New ProcessStartInfo
    With myFile
        .UseShellExecute = True
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        .FileName = fileName
        .Verb = "Print"
    End With
    Process.Start(myFile)
End Sub
```

More details and explaination about how this works can be found in my article here:
https://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/easy-way-to-print-files-to-default-printer/

Comment: I see an extra "`)`" at the end of your filename. Correct that and hopefully it should work.

Comment: thank you !! it works , but i have another problem , when i press print ( button) it opens  me the excel file which  I wanted to print..

Comment: That should happen only if there is no printer installed or there is some other problem with your system. The above code is just the equivalent of right-clicking on your file and clicking `Print` option from the popup menu. So if that works, this code should work too.